# How to change the Avatar picture of the root user in KDE Plasma?

Tags: kde

When I go to the user manager window of KDE (GUI) - there is no option to select the root user in order to change its avatar to another one. Now I tried making a new user and giving it a custom avatar via the user manager window of KDE and it works, however for the root user it seems I cannot change its avatar.

I am currently using KDE Plasma Version: 5.17.5, Framework Version: 5.70.0 and Qt Version: 5.14.2

The avatar picture I am using is of 256x256 size and is of .png format. I renamed the file as `root.face.icon`.

Methods I have tried but didn't work:

1. Put the avatar file in `/usr/share/sddm/faces`
2. Put the file in `/root` (Root's home folder)
3. Create a file called `avatars.conf` and add the line below to
   `/etc/sddm.conf.d/avatars.conf`

   ```
   [Theme]
   EnableAvatars=true # enable avatars
   ```

Links

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SDDM#User_avatars_do_not_show_up_on_the_greeter
- https://superuser.com/questions/685261/changing-kde-user-avatar

Comment: Your really shouldn't be logging in under `root` in KDE or any DE.